# react-router cannot navigate after Logout without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ecmascript-6, react-router

I use the following approach to logout and although there is no error on console and localHistory is cleaned successfully, it cannot navigate to login page without refreshing current page.

```js
const handleLogout = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  navigate("/login");
};
```

```
<Link onClick={() => handleLogout()}>
  <li><span>Logout</span>  </li>
</Link>
```

I am not sure if there is any need to add route for logout, but I also tried by adding like below:

```
<Route path="/logout" element={<Login />} />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Link` is missing a `to` prop. You can add the missing `to` prop and then prevent the default link action from occurring so you can issue clearing the localStorage.

Example:

```
const handleLogout = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();   // keep link from immediately navigating
  localStorage.clear(); // clear storage
  navigate("/login");   // now navigate away
};

...

<li>
  <Link to="/login" onClick={handleLogout}>
    <span>Logout</span>
  </Link>
</li>
```

If you *don't* actually need the link then you can attach the click handler to one of the other DOM elements. Be sure to maintain browser accessibility.

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  navigate("/login");
};

...

<li
  role="button"
  tabIndex={0}
  onClick={handleLogout}
  onKeyPress={handleLogout}
>
  <span>Logout</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Actually I solved the problem using `<li>`, but these are really very useful information for me. Because, I would not expect to use `to` parameter when I use `onClick()` in the `Link` (actually I removed `to` parameter. Now, based on the given info, should I use the same route (/login) on both; `to` and `navigate("/login");` ? Or can I remove from `handleLogout` method?

Comment: I just tried now and `navigate("/login")` parts seems unnecessary. Thank you so much.